# Two Lists, compare and show difference plus or minus

Tags: perl, sed, awk

Not 100% sure how to do this.  I guess I would that each list and make a array out of both.  I can get the differences but how would I list the difference?

List day 1

```
xxxx-r01 48
xxxx-r02 38
xxxx-r03 28
```

List Day 2

```
xxxx-r01 44
xxxx-r02 39
xxxx-r03 29
```

Desired result.

```
xxxx-r01 -4
xxxx-r02 1
xxxx-r03 1
```

Comment: All row IDs appears in both files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed number of columns (differences in the second field):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$2;next}{print $1,$2-a[FNR]}' list1 list2
xxxx-r01 -4
xxxx-r02 1
xxxx-r03 1
```

Variable number of columns (differences in the last field):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$NF;next}{$NF=$NF-a[FNR]}1' list1 list2
xxxx-r01 -4
xxxx-r02 1
xxxx-r03 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, you can do it like,

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @arr1 = ( "xxxx-r01 48", "xxxx-r02 38", "xxxx-r03 28");
my @arr2 = ( "xxxx-r01 44", "xxxx-r02 39", "xxxx-r03 29");

my %seen1 = map { split/ /, $_ } @arr1;
my %seen2 = map { split/ /, $_ } @arr2;


foreach my $test (keys %seen2) {
 my $diff = $seen2{$test} - $seen1{$test};
 print"$test:$diff\n";
}
```

Output:

```
xxxx-r01:-4
xxxx-r02:1
xxxx-r03:1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 join list1 list2 | awk '{print $1,$3-$2}'
```